# Select records from a result

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I've got following data as result from a query

| agr_no | cld_type_cd | from_dt | untl_dt | hour_qt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00000080064 | 3 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 | 5.00 |
| 00000080064 | 3 | 2021-02-17 | 2021-02-17 | 1.00 |
| 00000080064 | 4 | 2021-02-17 | 2021-02-17 | NULL |
| 00000080064 | 4 | 2021-02-17 | 2021-02-17 | 2.00 |
| 00000080064 | 4 | 2021-02-17 | 2021-02-17 | 1.00 |

The output I need is the following:

| agr_no | cld_type_cd | from_dt | untl_dt | hour_qt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00000080064 | 3 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 | 5.00 |
| 00000080064 | 4 | 2021-02-17 | 2021-02-17 | NULL |
| 00000080064 | 4 | 2021-02-17 | 2021-02-17 | 2.00 |
| 00000080064 | 4 | 2021-02-17 | 2021-02-17 | 1.00 |

The logic is: when there exists a record with cld_type_cd = 4 on the same from_dt and untl_dt with hour_qt NULL then the record with cld type cd = 3 on the same from dt and untl dt is not needed.

I am looking for an easy solution (1 query) if possible and not with temporary or common table expressions. Is it possible?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE(AGR_NO,CLD_TYPE_CD,FROM_DT,UNTL_DT,HOUR_QT) AS
(
   SELECT '00000080064' ,   3,  '2020-01-01' ,  '2020-01-01',   5.00
       UNION ALL
   SELECT '00000080064' ,   3 , '2021-02-17' ,  '2021-02-17' ,  1.00
       UNION ALL
   SELECT '00000080064' ,   4,  '2021-02-17' ,  '2021-02-17' ,  NULL
       UNION ALL
   SELECT '00000080064',    4,  '2021-02-17' ,  '2021-02-17' ,  2.00
      UNION ALL
   SELECT '00000080064',    4,  '2021-02-17',   '2021-02-17' ,  1.00
)

SELECT C.AGR_NO,C.CLD_TYPE_CD,C.FROM_DT,C.UNTL_DT,C.HOUR_QT
 FROM CTE AS C
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
   SELECT 1 FROM CTE AS C2 WHERE C.AGR_NO=C2.AGR_NO AND C2.CLD_TYPE_CD=4 AND   C.CLD_TYPE_CD=3
    AND C.FROM_DT=C2.FROM_DT AND C.UNTL_DT=C2.UNTL_DT AND C2.HOUR_QT IS NULL
```

)

Based on your data sample could you please try the above query if it is suitable for you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when cld_type_cd = 4 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by agr_no, from_dt, untl_dt) as num_4s
      from t
     ) t
where not (cld_type_cd = 3 and num_4s > 0);
```

The advantage of this version is that it refers to `t` only once.  So if this is a complex query, CTE, view, or function then this should be faster than solutions that reference it multiple times.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2f83e1413e821544b12902daf9be7b83) is a db<>fiddle.